# Select with Linq only unique TKey from List<Dictionary>

Tags: c#, linq

How to select from lists of dictionaries:

```
var dictionaries = new List<IDictionary<string, string>> { One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Nth};
```

only unique TKey with LINQ.

Comment: Please post sample code that compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Distinct:

```
dictionaries.SelectMany(d => d.Keys).Distinct();
```